# Не работает ajax с append

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Вот код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#writesform').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                        url: "../register/writes/wall_support.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "text",
                        data: {write: $('#textarea').val(), button: $('#sub').val()},
                        success: function(data) {
                            var arr = data.split('^');
                            var app = '<form><div>'arr[0]'Опубликовал 'arr[1]' администратор 'arr[2]'<button onclick="return delpost();" type="submit" name="number" value="'arr[3]'">удалить</button></div></form>';
                            $('.wall').append(app);
                        }
                })
                return false;
        });
    });
```

`Ajax` не работает в данном случае, но если из `append` убрать `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]`, `arr[3]`, то всё работает. В чём проблема?

Comment: ну так чё вы делаете?

    '<form><div>' + arr[0]+ 'Опубликовал ' + arr[1] + '...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу проблему как минимум в том, что конкатенация строк в js происходит через оператор "+".  Еще нельзя переносить строчки в строковых литералах.

Я вот очень люблю такой подход: [String.Format in JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/201899/String-Format-in-JavaScript).

P.S. Извиняюсь, что повторяюсь за [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre).

Comment: Я не спец, но там вроде точка для этого.